# Генерация html страниц

Tags: php

Привет всем.

Существует некая страница со ссылками на другие страницы, но другие страницы должны генерироваться по нажатию на ссылку, то есть иметь один общий шаблон. Проблема в том, что хоть суть этих страниц одинаковая, но количество одинаковых элементов на каждой странице различно. Нужно как-то придумать как это реализовать. 
Я представляю себе это так: тыкаем по ссылке, запускается функция, которая парсит тексовый файл и получает оттуда количество элементов, названия и описание их. Так мы получаем html страницу с нашими активными элементами.

Как это можно сделать поумнее и попроще? Получается, что всё равно нам нужно заполнять текстовый файл по определенным правилам. Это же лучше чем держать 300 html страничек или 300 функций для каждой. Или я не прав? Или что-то не понимаю) Спасибо.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь CMS (системой управления сайтом), рановато вам писать самописный сайт на чистом php

Comment: вам нужно ознакомиться с теорией Объектно ориентированного программирования и  MVC подхода. На пальцах этого вам не объяснить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Истина где-то рядом) Возьмите готовый движок, возможно вам вордпресс подойдёт, почитайте о нём, рассмотрите возможность изучения и дальнейшей реализации вашего проекта на этом движке. Если нет, то рассмотрите разные php фреймворки, например yii2 или laravel. У них порог вхождения невелик, легко освоить азы необходимые для реализации небольшого проекта. Принцип вы изложили где-то почти верно. Нужна единая точка входа, функция или объект, который будет смотреть на адрес по которому перешел пользователь и решать что делать, какой шаблон и каким образом собирать, а все данные необходимые хранятся в БД на сервере. Никаких текстовых файлов использовать не нужно, это слишком сложно и не рационально. За вас уже давно всё придумали, я дам несколько полезных ссылок по вышеперечисленным материалам:
https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/start-installation/
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/quickstart.what-is-yii
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals - реально классные видео от разработчика laravel, правда на английском.
https://ru.wordpress.org/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyDQwy63fMw - Видео знакомство с wordpress

Удачи вам!